# Are these conditions equivalent to the definition of the limit of a sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

The definition of the limit of sequence:

> We call $x$ the limit of the sequence $(x_{n})$ if the following condition holds:
>
> For each real number $\varepsilon >0$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that, for every natural number $n\geq N$, we have $|x_{n}-x|<\varepsilon$.

Now give some different conditions:

> For each real number $\varepsilon >0$，there exists a **natural number $N$** and **a constant $x_{\varepsilon}$** such that, for every natural number $n\geq N$, we have $|x_{n}-x_{\varepsilon}|<\varepsilon$.

My question is

> Are the above conditions equivalent to $\lim x_n = x$ (the definition of the limit of sequence)?

Comment: Hint: $|x_n-x_m|<2\epsilon$ for $n, m \geq N$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are. It is clear that if $\lim x_n=x$, then those “different conditions” hold.

Now, suppose that the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is not convergent. Then it is not a Cauchy sequence, which means that, for some $\varepsilon>0$, there are, for any $N\in\Bbb N$, natural numbers $m,n\geqslant N$ such that $|x_m-x_n|\geqslant\varepsilon$. But then there is no $N\in\Bbb N$ and no $x^\star\in\Bbb R$ such that $n\geqslant N\implies|x_n-x^\star|<\frac\varepsilon2$.

Comment: The sequence $(1/n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $\mathbb R^+$ is not convergent yet it's still Cauchy...

Comment: @CiaPan My answer is valid in $\Bbb R$ under the usual distance. I have no reason to believe that the OP was interested in anything other than that.

Comment: You believe. And I believe, too. But the definition does not believe. Definition doesn't specify it applies to reals only or all compact spaces only. The definition is general, and conclusions are general. However in particular they appear wrong, so generally they are wrong. They just need a minor specific clarification: _"in real numbers ..."_ (:

Answer (score 2):

Your second set of conditions is equivalent to the definition of a [Cauchy sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence), so yes, this is equivalent to the sequence being convergent.

A sequence is Cauchy if for any $\epsilon$, we can find an interval of length $\epsilon$ which the sequence is eventually contained in. Your $\epsilon_m$ is simply the center of that interval.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the above conditions you stated stray from the notion of limit in the sense $\lim x_n = x$, and are more useful for evaluating what *type* of sequence you are dealing with. Like Cauchy sequences for example.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, they aren't, because the first one *names* a limit value and defines a condition under which it exists whilst the second one defines a condition only and says nothing about the existence of the limit value $x$.

As a result the first one is a definition of a convergent sequence (e.g. a real sequence of $\lfloor 10^n\,\pi\rfloor/10^n$ in $\mathbb R$ for natural $n$) and the second is a definition of a Cauchy sequence (e.g. a sequence of $\lfloor 10^n\,\pi\rfloor/10^n$ in $\mathbb Q$ for natural $n$).

Comment: but the sequence $(x_n)$ is convergent if and only if $(x_n)$ is Cauchy sequence.

Comment: @maplgebra Not true. See the example above of decimal truncations of $\pi$. Or a simpler one: $(1/n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $(0,\infty)$ – it is Cauchy, but it has no limit.

Comment: Seem you consider the the field of sequence, but i think it suppose to be $\mathbb{R}$.